# How to use Tailwind CSS with Quasar framework?

Tags: tailwind-css, quasar-framework, quasar

I have been trying to use Tailwind to custom the Quasar components, but the Quasar CSS has been overwriting most of the Tailwind CSS.

I added a prefix to my `tailwind.config.js` and my Tailwind classes are prefixed with tw- like in the example below.

```
module.exports = {
  prefix: 'tw-',
}
```

Comment: I think you will be better off with the Quasar's inbuilt CSS utilities which offer most of the features of Tailwind CSS.

Comment: @Chin.Udara  That's not true. Quasar's inbuilt CSS utilities don't have a way to set the width and height of an element, for instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is [a dedicated issue on Quasar's github](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/issues/6775)

As a Quasar dev said, [`prefixing tailwind classes is the recommended way`](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/issues/6775#issuecomment-865974606) of doing so. So you're right!

To go deeper, [the most interesting part](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/issues/6775#issuecomment-955822836) seems about using `Unocss` to play with [its presets for other frameworks like Tailwind](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/issues/6775#issuecomment-955822836)

#### Edit

It seems like the team is considering `UnoCSS` integration and making Quasar's CSS swappable with Tailwind for `Quasar v3` https://github.com/orgs/quasarframework/projects/2?pane=issue&itemId=1451670

Answer (score 5):

for me i had to use .css instead of .scss which quasar use as global css
so steps below

install

```bash
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npx tailwindcss init -p
```

tailwind.config.js

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['./index.html', './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,vue}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

postcss.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('autoprefixer')({
      overrideBrowserslist: [
        'last 4 Chrome versions',
        'last 4 Firefox versions',
        'last 4 Edge versions',
        'last 4 Safari versions',
        'last 4 Android versions',
        'last 4 ChromeAndroid versions',
        'last 4 FirefoxAndroid versions',
        'last 4 iOS versions',
      ],
    }),
    require('tailwindcss'),
  ],
};
```

quasar.config.js

```js
    css: ['app.scss', 'tailwind.css'],
```

tailwind.css

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Answer (score 4):

We were able to get TailwindCSS working with Quasar using unocss (which supports TailwindCSS syntax).

We followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SpRfYw1p6bA) but in a gist this is what you need to do:

Install unocss webpack package and a preset:

```bash
yarn install -D @unocss/webpack
yarn install -D @unocss/preset-uno
```

Create a boot file cass UnoCSS.js in src/boot/ with the following:

```scss
import 'uno.css'
```

Update your quasar.config.js

```js
const UnoCSS = require('@unocss/webpack').default
const presetUno = require('@unocss/preset-uno').default

module.exports = configure(function (ctx) {
   // ...
   boot: [
      'UnoCss' // name of your boot file
   ]
   // ...
    build: {
      // ...
      extendWebpack (cfg) {
        cfg.plugins.push(UnoCSS({
          presets: [
            presetUno()
          ]
        }))
      },
      // ...
    }
    //...
}
```

Start your dev server with `quasar dev`

And you should be able to use any TailwindCSS classes.

Note: styles do not auto refresh on the page when you update you need to manually refresh the page to see the changes.